# ItemsControl not updating after data change to an ObservableCollection<T> property

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have the following test code…
XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Test.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Test"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:data="using:Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Name="StartButton" Content="Start" Click="StartButton_Click" Height="30" Width="200"/>

        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray" ItemsSource="{x:Bind RowItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:MyData">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FirstName}" Margin="10,0,5,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Surname}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class MyData
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoadData
    {
        public static void Get_RowItems(ObservableCollection<MyData> Items)
        {
            Items.Add(new MyData() { FirstName = "John", Surname = "Doe" });
        }
    }

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MyData> RowItems;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            RowItems = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
            LoadData.Get_RowItems(RowItems);
        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RowItems[0].FirstName = "Bill";
        }
    }
}
```

On running it, the ItemsControl displays the first line of data (John Doe) fine.

When the Start button is clicked, the underlying data changes to Bill Doe (as expected)

But, the ItemsControl stubbornly continues to display: John Doe

I’ve read so many articles relating to this kind of issue and none of the solutions seem to work (if I’ve implemented them correctly) so now I can’t see the wood for the trees.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Class MyData has to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise a PropertyChanged event when the FirstName property changes. ObservableCollection won't help here, because the collection isn't changed.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for your response. I have read much about INotifyPropertyChanged and raising a PropertyChanged event but all efforts to do that have not worked. Implementation issue I imagine. Can you show how I would do that successfully in this project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @Clemens said, you should just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` event at the `MyData` class to notify UI when properties of the class are changed.

```
public class MyData:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //public string FirstName { get; set; }
    private string firstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    private string surName;

    public string Surname
    {
        get { return surName; }
        set { surName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Surname");

        }
    }

    //public string Surname { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

You're not modifying the `ObservableCollection` itself (such as adding/removing items) but the items **INSIDE** that collection. The `ObservableCollection` is responsible for notifying its own changes, not changes pertaining to its items. You Should NotifyPropertyChange("EachYourProperty") in the `setter` of your `MyData` class and your UI will be updated.

And change your binding of your`TextBlock` and "Surname" properties to "OneWay" cause by default it is set to "OneTime":

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FirstName, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,0,5,0"/>
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Surname, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

[As MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode(v=vs.110).aspx):

**One-way** - Updates the binding target (target) property when the binding source (source) changes. This type of binding is appropriate if the control being bound is implicitly read-only.

**One-time** - Updates the binding target when the application starts or when the data context changes. This type of binding is appropriate if you are using data where either a snapshot of the current state is appropriate to use or the data is truly static.

**Update 1:**

If you have time-consuming operation after changing an item of `ObservableCollection<T>`, it is better to perform time-consuming operation at non-UI thread:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        coll[0].FirstName = "Bill";
        Task.Run(()=> {
               Thread.Sleep(5000);
               MessageBox.Show("");
                       });
    }
```

Comment: Yes that seems to have done the trick, it needed a 'using System.ComponentModel' to be added for other strugglers. Also the comments from @gregstoll were needed too. I.E Mode=OneWay added to all x:Bind statements in the XAML. Thanks both.

Comment: Is it possible to ask a supplementary question here? I notice the ItemsControl only updates after the StartButton_Click event handler (and hence the program) has finished. I really need the view to change as each property is changed, i.e. as soon as RowItems[0].FirstName = "Bill"; is preformed and before the event handler's return. Is that possible?

Comment: @gaw it is better to ask new question to avoid mixing questions and keep clearness the topic

Comment: @gaw are you doing time consuming operation after changing property?

Comment: As suggested I've posed it as another question here> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34256797/itemscontrol-not-updating-immediately-after-property-value-change?noredirect=1#comment56255313_34256797) It also has the corrected code as per your original answer above.

Answer (score 3):

Clemens is correct.  In addition, the default for x:Bind is a OneTime binding, so it won't ever get updated.  Instead you need something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind FirstName, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,0,5,0"/>
```

and the same thing for everywhere else you're using x:Bind.

Answer (score 2):

Based on provided answers you can go a little further and define a common class for your entities and also notify in a strongly type way the view that the property value has changed:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the PropertyChanged event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property</param>
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var ev = PropertyChanged;
        if (ev != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the PropertyChanged event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="expr">Lambda expression that identifies the updated property</param>
    public void OnPropertyChanged<TProp>(Expression<Func<BaseEntity, TProp>> expr) 
    {
        var prop = (MemberExpression)expr.Body;
        OnPropertyChanged(prop.Member.Name);
    }
}

public class MyData : BaseEntity 
{
    private string firstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; OnPropertyChanged(e => FirstName); }
    }

    private string surName;
    public string Surname
    {
        get { return surName; }
        set { surName = value; OnPropertyChanged(e => Surname); }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with this one. **BaseDataContract** can't be found??

Comment: Sorry, just a glitch in my code (it was adapted from one of my projects). Please, check it now.

Comment: I still get an error but this time 'BaseEntity does not contain a definition for FirstName ...' ( from e.FirstName) ditto for e.Surname?

Comment: I have finally had the time to test it properly. Yes, OnPropertyChanged calls should provide item => Property, as the property from actual class is provided, no from the BaseEntity.

Comment: That's better. Works perfectly. Thanks for your efforts! Again for anyone else's benefit, this needs 'using System.ComponentModel;' added.